# How can I load the #totals property for the receipt theme in a custom module?

Tags: commerce

I am trying to manually output the customer's receipt on the checkout complete screen in a custom module.

I have the receipt printing nicely except for the "totals" variable.

My current custom code is the following.

```
$renderable = array(
      '#theme' => 'commerce_order_receipt',
      '#order_entity' => $order,
      '#billing_information' => NULL,
      '#shipping_information' => NULL,
      '#payment_method' => NULL,
      '#totals' => $this->orderTotalSummary->buildTotals($order), // <-- this is the problem
    );
```

```
 return array(
      '#theme' => 'custom_blocks_checkout_complete',
 '#order' =>  \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($renderable),
    );
```

As you can see, it's using `$this->orderTotalSummary->buildTotals($order)` to generate the #totals property and this was copied from the OrderReceiptMail class in the Order module. How can I get this property to populate from my custom module please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the service

```
'#totals' => \Drupal::service('commerce_order.order_total_summary')->buildTotals($order),
```

Comment: You are a genius my friend. Many thanks!